# Collections in scala, how to get elements in map

Tags: scala

From [lift-json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json):

```
scala> val json = parse("""
         {
           "name": "joe",
           "addresses": {
             "address1": {
               "street": "Bulevard",
               "city": "Helsinki"
             },
             "address2": {
               "street": "Soho",
               "city": "London"
             }
           }
         }""")
scala> case class Address(street:String, city: String)
scala> case class PersonWithAddresses(name: String, addresses: Map[String, Address])
scala> val joe = json.extract[PersonWithAddresses]
res0: PersonWithAddresses("joe", Map("address1" -> Address("Bulevard", "Helsinki"),
                                     "address2" -> Address("Soho", "London")))
```

I want to access elements of `joe`. I want to know the Joe's `address1 city` for example. How?

Bonus Question: 
what if `PersonWithAddresses` was

> `case class PersonWithAddress(name:String, addresses: Map[String, List[Address]])`

how would I extract the size of that list?

P.S. question:
what's the difference between  `joe.addresses("address1").size()` and
`joe.addresses.get("address1").size`  ?

Comment: `joe.addresses("address1").city` and `joe.addresses("address1").size()`

Comment: GENIUS! 
what's the difference between  `joe.addresses("address1").size()` and
`joe.addresses.get("address1").size`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has nothing really to do with json and lift itself. You already have your object, you just don't know how to use scala collections.

In case without list, you can get your city with:

```
@ joe.addresses("address1") 
res4: Address = Address("Bulevard", "Helsinki")
@ res4.city 
res5: String = "Helsinki"
```

or `joe.addresses("address1").city` for short.

In case of list

```
case class PersonWithAddress(name:String, addresses: Map[String, List[Address]])
```

you just call `size` on list.

```
joe.addresses("address1").size
```

As for a difference between these two:

```
@ res7.addresses("address1").size 
res8: Int = 1
@ res7.addresses.get("address1").size 
res9: Int = 1
```

There is a big difference, see what happens when you call `get`

```
@ res7.addresses.get("address1") 
res10: Option[List[Address]] = Some(List(Address("Bulevard", "Helsinki")))
```

It returns an `Option` which could be viewed as a collection of size 0 or 1. Checking its size is not what you want to do.

```
map.get("key")
```

returns an `Option` which is either `Some(value)` if value is present in map, or `None` if it's not

`map("key")` or desugared `map.apply("key")` returns the item associated with key or exception if element is not present in the map.